# Find basis for $U$ and $W$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this problem :

> $U,W \subseteq R^4$
>
> Base of $W = \{w1 = (1,2,2,-2), w2 = (0,1,2,-1)\}$
>
> Base of $U = \{u1 = (1,1,0,-1),u2 = (0,1,3,1)\}$
>
> Find a basis for $U \cap W$.

**My solution**

for any $v \in U \cap W$, $v \in W$ and $v \in U$

I need to find $\lambda_1...\lambda_4$ that appiles:

$$\lambda_1u1+\lambda_2u2=\lambda_3w1+\lambda_4w2$$

Hence (put the vectors as colums),

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & -1 & 0       \\
2 & 1 & -1 & -1       \\
2 & 2 & 0 & -3       \\
-2 & -1 & 1 & -1
\end{array}\right]$$

After elementary operations:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & -1 & 0       \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0       \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1      \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]$$

Therefore :

$$\lambda_1=\lambda_3$$

$$\lambda_2=-\lambda_3$$

$$\lambda_3=\text{arbitrary}$$

$$\lambda_4=0$$

Therefore basis of $U \cap W=\operatorname{Sp}\{(1,-1,1,0)\}$

For some reason I don't get the same results as the book.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly computed the set of $(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_4)$ such that $\lambda_1w_1+\lambda_2w_2=\lambda_3u_1+\lambda_4u_2$ (your question mixes up $u$ and $w$ half way). That was not however the question; the question was to find the corresponding values of the left-hand-side of the equation (which are of course also values of the right-hand-side). That's $\{\,\lambda_3w_1-\lambda_3w_2\mid\lambda_3\in\Bbb R\,\}$, which is the line spanned by $w_1-w_2=(1,1,0,-1)$, which happens to be$~u_1$ (why this is so is more clear if you look at the right-hand-side, where $\lambda_4=0$).

Comment: Does the answer of your book say $sp(-1,0,-1,1)?$

Comment: @Shailesh: My book???

Comment: No, I mean the book from which you are solving this question.